# Better way of comparing substrings than a giant if loop

Tags: php, if-statement, substr

Alright so, in my code, I have a URL, and it gets passed into my function: `testURL($url)`, which, in order:

1. Tests the `base url` whether it's the domain (`'http://www.example.com'`)
2. Tests the various substrings:

   - `ShowForum`
   - `Amex`
   - `Owners`
   - `ManagementCenter`
   - `WeatherUnderground`
   - `MapPopup`
   - `asp`
   - `pages`
3. Returns `true` if it has the `base url`, but doesn't match the substrings, otherwise `return false;`

Here's the code

```
function testURL($url){
    if ((substr($url, 0, 23) == "http://www.example.com/") && (substr($url, 23, 3) != "asp") && (substr($url, 23, 4) != "Amex") && (substr($url, 23, 5) != "pages")  && (substr($url, 23, 16) != "ManagementCenter") && (substr($url, 23, 16) != "Owners")  && (substr($url, 23, 9) != "ShowForum") && (substr($url, 23, 8) != "MapPopup") && (substr($url, 23, 18) != "WeatherUnderground")) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true;  
    }
```

Example:

```
testURL('http://www.example.com/Amex'); --> returns true
testURL('http://www.example.com/PayPal'); --> returns false
```

It's called in my case like:

```
if (testURL('http://www.example.com/Visa')){
  return;
}
```

The banned substrings list **will** get bigger as time goes on.
So, is there a better way to match substrings of variable lengths then that giant [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) loop?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: whats the big picture? where are the urls from? and here are they being used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Here I just parse the url with [`parse_url()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php), where then I check if the host matches and also if the path isn't in the array with [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php))

```
<?php

    function testURL($url) {
        $parsed = parse_url($url);
        if($parsed["host"] == "www.example.com" && !in_array(explode("/", $parsed["path"])[1], ["asp", "Amex", "WeatherUnderground", "MapPopup", "ShowForum", "Owners", "ManagementCenter", "pages"]))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

?>
```

Comment: What sbout if the page url is `/pages/aboutus.html`?

Comment: @Quill The questions what you want to do? Do you still only want to compare the first text e.g. `pages` here?

Comment: I want to compare whether the url fits within the folders designated. Meaning that because it's in the `/pages` directory, it'll `return false`.